# How to prevent windows 10 to create random new network adapters?

Tags: windows-10, networking, virtualbox

I am using windows 10 and I have trouble with network adapters. When I leave the laptop for some time, put it to sleep or restart a hardware network adaptor is randomly recognized as a different device.

At one time the hardware adaptor is "registered" as device "Ethernet"

[image]

then one hour later (logging in again) the same hardware adaptor is "registered" as device "Ethernet 5"

[image]

confusing all apps that might be using these adaptors (especially the VM). I then have to shutdown the VM (saving everything), then change the network setting, then restart the VM.

How can I tell windows to not randomly assign the same hardware adaptor to other random devices? Is that possible? Is that better in windows 11 (then I will migrate)?

Comment: Windows has been doing this since at least XP :\

Comment: (1) If you right-click the adapter and select "Rename", does the new name stick. (2) What is the exact model of the adapter?

Comment: I have never seen this, and I am using this very driver with my Thunderbolt docking station. Does any of the devices on the path to the controller have incorrect/missing USB serial numbers?